# MATLAB: rolling z-score

Tags: matlab

I have a `3650x1` column vector of time series data in ascending order from 1/1/2000 through 12/31/2010. This means that the observations are in rows and the 1/1/2000 observation is in the first row and the 12/31/2010 observation is in the last row.

I also have a row vector of offsets and an empty matrix called `z_scores`:

```
offsets = [5 10 15 20]
z_scores = nan(3650, 4)
```

I am trying to populate `z_scores`. Each column in `z_scores` corresponds to a series of `offset` z-scores.

For example, the first column of `z_scores` will contain z-scores of 5 periods. The second column of `z_scores` will contain z-scores of 10 periods, etc. The first `offset` indicies of `z_scores` will be `NaN` in each column.

Currently, I loop through `offsets` which is fine. However I would prefer a vectorized solution in each iteration of `offset` if possible.

```
for i=1:length(offset)

    z_scores(:, i) = (data() - mean()) / std() % help!

end
```

I have all the toolboxes so I can use built in functions. If someone wants to suggest a non-vectorized solution, I would be happy do see it!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1:length(offsets)
    N = offsets(i);
    z_scores(1:N, i) = zscore(data(1:N));
end
```